# barcode on pos tilslip

Tags: delphi, barcode, point-of-sale

very new to the site 
i have delphi pos 
and want to add bar code to the tillslip template the bar code need to be at the bottom of the page and it will be the document ID
    the barcode need to be EAN 128

```
  HEADER]
    SELECT * FROM SALES_TRANSACTION_HEADER
    JOIN STORES ON (ST_ID=TH_STORE_ID)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN USERS ON (US_STORE_ID=TH_STORE_ID AND US_ID=TH_USER_ID)
    WHERE TH_ID=?DOCUMENT_ID AND TH_STORE_ID=?STORE_ID AND TH_TYPE=?DOCUMENT_TYPE

   DETAIL]
    SELECT * FROM SALES_TRANSACTION_DETAIL
    JOIN PRINTER_CATEGORY ON (PRC_STORE_ID=?THIS_STORE_ID AND PRC_WORKSTATION_ID=?THIS_WORKSTATION_ID AND PRC_PRINTER_ID=?THIS_PRINTER_ID AND PRC_CATEGORY_ID=TD_CATEGORY_ID1)
    JOIN STORES ON (ST_ID=TD_STORE_ID)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SALES_REPS ON (SR_ID=TD_SALESREP_ID AND ((ST_GLOBAL_REPS = 0 AND SR_STORE_ID=TD_STORE_ID) OR (ST_GLOBAL_REPS  0 AND SR_STORE_ID=(SELECT ST_ID FROM STORES WHERE ST_TYPE = 2))))
    WHERE TD_DOCUMENT_ID=?DOCUMENT_ID AND TD_STORE_ID=?STORE_ID AND TD_TYPE=?DOCUMENT_TYPE

    [SQL_PAYMENT]
    SELECT * FROM SALES_TRANSACTION_PAYMENT 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TENDER_TYPES ON (TT_ID=TP_TENDER_ID)
    WHERE TP_DOCUMENT_ID=?DOCUMENT_ID AND TP_STORE_ID=?STORE_ID AND TP_TYPE=?DOCUMENT_TYPE


    [HEADER]
    
    +
    +[PRINTLOGO]
    +
    
    
    +   TAX INVOICE
    
    
    +
    +CASH SALE
    +Document ID: ~0ddddddd;
        !TH_ID

    @IF !TH_PRINTED_COUNT THEN
    + COPY ~D
        !TH_PRINTED_COUNT
    @ELSE
    +
    @ENDIF

    +~SSSSSSSSS                      ~SSSSSSS
    !TH_TRANSACTION_DATE,!TH_TRANSACTION_TIME
    +

    +~SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
    !ST_COMPANYNAME

    @IF !ST_PHYSICALADDR1 THEN
    +~SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
      !ST_PHYSICALADDR1
    @ENDIF

    @IF !ST_PHYSICALADDR2 THEN
    +~SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
      !ST_PHYSICALADDR2
    @ENDIF

    @IF !ST_PHYSICALADDR3 THEN
    +~SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
      !ST_PHYSICALADDR3
    @ENDIF

    @IF !ST_PHYSICALADDR4 THEN
    +~SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
      !ST_PHYSICALADDR4
    @ENDIF

    @IF !ST_PHYSICALADDR5 THEN
    +~SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
      !ST_PHYSICALADDR5
    @ENDIF

    @IF !ST_TELEPHONE1 THEN
    +
    +Telephone: ~SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
      !ST_TELEPHONE1
    @ENDIF

    @IF !ST_FAX THEN
    +      Fax: ~SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
      !ST_FAX
    @ENDIF

    @IF !ST_TAX_NUMBER THEN
    +VAT Reg #: ~SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
    !ST_TAX_NUMBER
    @ENDIF

    @IF !TH_CUSTOMER_NAME THEN
    +
    +To:~SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
    !TH_CUSTOMER_NAME
    @ENDIF

    @IF !TH_ADDRESS_1 THEN
    +   ~SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
    !TH_ADDRESS_1
    @ENDIF

    @IF !TH_ADDRESS_2 THEN
    +   ~SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
    !TH_ADDRESS_2
    @ENDIF

    @IF !TH_ADDRESS_3 THEN
    +   ~SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
    !TH_ADDRESS_3
    @ENDIF

    @IF !TH_ADDRESS_4 THEN
    +   ~SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
    !TH_ADDRESS_4
    @ENDIF

    @IF !TH_ADDRESS_5 THEN
    +   ~SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
    !TH_ADDRESS_5
    @ENDIF
    @IF !TH_TELEPHONE THEN
    +Telephone: ~SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
    !TH_TELEPHONE
    @ENDIF

    @IF !TH_ACCOUNTCODE THEN
    +Account No: ~SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
    !TH_ACCOUNTCODE
    @ENDIF

    @IF !TH_EXEMPT_TAX_NUMBER THEN
    +Tax Number:~SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
    !TH_EXEMPT_TAX_NUMBER
    @ENDIF

    @IF !TH_ORDER_NUMBER THEN
    +Order Number:~SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
    !TH_ORDER_NUMBER
    @ENDIF

    +
    
    +Description        Unit  
    +Item Code          Price   Qty     Nett
    +---------------------------------------
    


    [DETAIL]
    @IF (!TD_ITEMTYPE  3) THEN
    +~SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
    !TD_DESCRIPTION
    @ELSE
    +~SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
    !TD_DESCRIPTION
    @ENDIF
    +~SSSSSSSSSSSSSSS ~fff.ff ~ff.q ~ffff.ff; 
    !TD_PRODUCTCODE,!TD_RETAIL_PRICE,!TD_QTY,!TD_LINE_VALUE

    @IF !TD_LINE_TAX_ID = 0 THEN
    +*;
    @ELSEIF !TD_LINE_TAX_ID = 2 THEN
    +#;
    @ENDIF
    +

    @IF !TD_DISCOUNT_AMOUNT  0 THEN
    + Discount on above line ~ffff.ff
      !TD_DISCOUNT_AMOUNT
    @ENDIF

    @IF (!TD_ITEMTYPE = 2) AND (!TD_COLOUR_PACK_SERIAL  '') THEN
    +Colour/Size:~SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
    !TD_COLOUR_PACK_SERIAL
    @ENDIF

    @IF (!TD_ITEMTYPE = 3) AND (!TD_COLOUR_PACK_SERIAL  '') THEN
    +Serial #:~SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
      !TD_COLOUR_PACK_SERIAL
    @ENDIF

    $COUNT=0
    
    @WHILE $COUNT 

    [SUMMARY]
    +---------------------------------------
    @IF !TH_TRANSACTION_TAX_TYPE THEN
    +                SUB-TOTAL: ~ffffffff.ff
    !TH_TRANSACTION_TOTAL - !TH_TRANSACTION_TAX - !TH_ADMIN_FEE + !TH_OVERALL_DISCOUNT + !TH_ROUNDING_LOSS
    @ELSEIF (!TH_ADMIN_FEE  0) OR (!TH_OVERALL_DISCOUNT  0) OR (!TH_ROUNDING_LOSS  0) THEN
    +                SUB-TOTAL: ~ffffffff.ff
    !TH_TRANSACTION_TOTAL - !TH_ADMIN_FEE + !TH_OVERALL_DISCOUNT + !TH_ROUNDING_LOSS
    @ENDIF

    @IF !TH_OVERALL_DISCOUNT THEN
    +     ~sssssssssssssssssss: ~ffffffff.ff
    'DISCOUNT (' + !TH_OVERALL_PERCENT + '%)', -!TH_OVERALL_DISCOUNT
    @ENDIF

    @IF !TH_ADMIN_FEE THEN
    +             ADMIN CHARGE: ~ffffffff.ff
    !TH_ADMIN_FEE
    @ENDIF

    @IF !TH_TRANSACTION_TAX_TYPE THEN
    +                      VAT: ~ffffffff.ff
    !TH_TRANSACTION_TAX

    @ELSE
    +             VAT INCLUDED: ~ffffffff.ff
    !TH_TRANSACTION_TAX
    @ENDIF

    @IF !TH_ROUNDING_LOSS  0 THEN
    +            ROUNDING LOSS: ~ffffffff.ff
    -!TH_ROUNDING_LOSS
    @ENDIF

    @IF (!TH_TRANSACTION_TAX_TYPE > 0) OR (!TH_ADMIN_FEE  0) OR (!TH_OVERALL_DISCOUNT  0) OR (!TH_ROUNDING_LOSS  0) THEN
    +                           ------------
    @ENDIF

    +                    TOTAL: ~ffffffff.ff
    !TH_TRANSACTION_TOTAL


    @IF !TH_DEPOSIT_AMOUNT THEN
    +             LESS DEPOSIT: ~ffffffff.ff
    -!TH_DEPOSIT_AMOUNT
    +      TOTAL AFTER DEPOSIT: ~ffffffff.ff
    !TH_TRANSACTION_TOTAL - !TH_DEPOSIT_AMOUNT
    @ENDIF
    +                           ------------

    @IF $PAYMENTCOUNT > 0 THEN
    $CHANGE = 0
    $COUNTER = 0

    &FIRSTPAYMENT

    @WHILE $COUNTER  0 THEN
    +~ssssssssssssssssssssssss: ~ffffffff.ff
    !TT_NAME + ' CHANGE', -!TP_AMOUNT
    @IF !TP_NUMBER THEN
    +~ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
    !TT_NAME + ' #: ' + !TP_NUMBER
    @ENDIF
    @ENDIF

    $COUNTER = $COUNTER + 1

    &NEXTPAYMENT

    @ENDWHILE

    @ENDIF

    [FOOTER]
    +---------------------------------------
    +User: ~SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS Wks: ~DD
    !US_NAME, !TH_WORKSTATION_ID
    + Rep: ~SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
    !DETAIL.SR_NAME

    @IF !TH_OUR_REFERENCE  '' THEN
    + Our Reference: ~SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
    !TH_OUR_REFERENCE
    @ENDIF
    @IF !TH_YOUR_REFERENCE  '' THEN
    +Your Reference: ~SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
    !TH_YOUR_REFERENCE
    @ENDIF

    @IF $MESSAGE1 THEN
    +~SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
    $MESSAGE1
    @ENDIF
    @IF $MESSAGE2 THEN
    +~SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
    $MESSAGE2
    @ENDIF
    @IF $MESSAGE3 THEN
    +~SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
    $MESSAGE3
    @ENDIF
    @IF $MESSAGE4 THEN
    +~SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
    $MESSAGE4
    @ENDIF
    @IF $MESSAGE5 THEN
    +~SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
    $MESSAGE5
    @ENDIF
```

Comment: Yes, but what's your question?  You want to print a barcode from a Delphi app?

Comment: Btw this freeware library http://sourceforge.net/projects/tpsystools/ includes components for printing barcodes, including EAN ones.  But SO isn't for component recommendations, nor for Delphi coding tutorials.

Comment: What should we do with all the template stuff? We do not know the program working with that template although it seems to be written in delphi. I can give you a template from one of my progs (written also in delphi), do you think that would help you?

Comment: what i want to do is use the document id and print that document id as an EAN128 barcode at the end of the slip